# How to get PID by process name?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pid

Is there any way I can get the PID by process name in Python?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                        
 3110 meysam    20   0  971m 286m  63m S  14.0  7.9  14:24.50 chrome
```

For example I need to get `3110` by `chrome`.

Comment: There can be more processes with the same name and different PIDs

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get the pid of processes by name using `pidof` through [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])


In [5]: get_pid("java")
Out[5]: '23366\n'
```

`check_output(["pidof",name])` will run the command as `"pidof process_name"`, *If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.*

To handle multiple entries and cast to ints:

```
from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return map(int,check_output(["pidof",name]).split())
```

In [21]: get_pid("chrome")

```
Out[21]: 
[27698, 27678, 27665, 27649, 27540, 27530, 27517, 14884, 14719, 13849, 13708, 7713, 7310, 7291, 7217, 7208, 7204, 7189, 7180, 7175, 7166, 7151, 7138, 7127, 7117, 7114, 7107, 7095, 7091, 7087, 7083, 7073, 7065, 7056, 7048, 7028, 7011, 6997]
```

Or pas the `-s` flag to get a single pid:

```
def get_pid(name):
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))

In [25]: get_pid("chrome")
Out[25]: 27698
```

Comment: +1 seems like a perfect  answer. could you explain this `return check_output(["pidof",name])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, added an explanation, hopefully makes it a little more clear

Comment: Why not go through /proc entries instead of calling external tools? While common in bash scripts, it's usually not very clean to do so in python scripts. Also, what if there are multiple processes with that name? I would at least `splitlines()` the output and covert the pids to ints.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, what is not clean about using the pidof command?

Comment: Is it even available by default on all/most linux systems?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, as far as I know yes it is. Also I used split with map to convert to ints and handle the case  *if there are multiple processes with that name*. I still don't get your problem with using the command. parsing the top output will also give multiple process id's

Comment: Note that check_output() is not available in Python 2.6 and older versions.

Comment: @JaimeM., it is pretty trivial to implement https://gist.github.com/edufelipe/1027906

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What does it mean when I get the CalledProcessError and how do it fix it to get the process Id. 
I am trying to make the script and run in OpenWRT.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Since the poster of this answer has not been active, I turn to you. When I use the first snippet of code, it throws a `FileNotFoundError`. Why is this?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath if you run the snippet on a device without a pidof command such as Windows, the command will not be found. This could be one reason.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `psutil` package:

**Install**

```
pip install psutil
```

**Usage:**

```py
import psutil

process_name = "chrome"
pid = None

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if process_name in proc.name():
       pid = proc.pid
       break

print("Pid:", pid)
```

Comment: Works perfectly with Python 3, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

you can also use `pgrep`, in `prgep` you can also give pattern for match

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep','program_name'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = child.communicate()[0]
```

you can also use `awk` with ps  like this

```
ps aux | awk '/name/{print $2}'
```

Comment: You could use one of the helper functions in the subprocess module.. much more readable. Also, executing it inside a shell is a really bad idea!

Comment: yep its just a concept, I have given to OP

Comment: it is better to run with `shell=False`.

Comment: Great answer! I've written a complete example based on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712205/304209

Answer (score 11):

For posix (Linux, BSD, etc... only need /proc directory to be mounted) it's easier to work with os files in /proc.
It's pure python, no need to call shell programs outside.

Works on python 2 and 3 ( The only difference (2to3) is the Exception tree, therefore the "*except Exception*", which I dislike but kept to maintain compatibility. Also could've created a custom exception.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys


for dirname in os.listdir('/proc'):
    if dirname == 'curproc':
        continue

    try:
        with open('/proc/{}/cmdline'.format(dirname), mode='rb') as fd:
            content = fd.read().decode().split('\x00')
    except Exception:
        continue

    for i in sys.argv[1:]:
        if i in content[0]:
            print('{0:<12} : {1}'.format(dirname, ' '.join(content)))
```

Sample Output (it works like pgrep):

```
phoemur ~/python $ ./pgrep.py bash
1487         : -bash 
1779         : /bin/bash
```

Comment: On Solaris family /proc is binary, not textual.

Answer (score 10):

Complete example based on the excellent @Hackaholic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689265/304209):

```
def get_process_id(name):
    """Return process ids found by (partial) name or regex.

    >>> get_process_id('kthreadd')
    [2]
    >>> get_process_id('watchdog')
    [10, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61]  # ymmv
    >>> get_process_id('non-existent process')
    []
    """
    child = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    response = child.communicate()[0]
    return [int(pid) for pid in response.split()]
```

Answer (score 6):

To improve the Padraic's answer: when `check_output` returns a non-zero code, it raises a CalledProcessError. This happens when the process does not exists or is not running.

What I would do to catch this exception is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

def getPIDs(process):
    try:
        pidlist = map(int, check_output(["pidof", process]).split())
    except  CalledProcessError:
        pidlist = []
    print 'list of PIDs = ' + ', '.join(str(e) for e in pidlist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getPIDs("chrome")
```

The output:

```
$ python pidproc.py
list of PIDS = 31840, 31841, 41942
```

Comment: In this case, since we aren't going anything useful in try/catch, we can also  use `subprocess.call` rather than `subprocess.check_output` with try/catch block.

Comment: @RajanPonnappan With `subprocess.call` you only gets the return code ($?), however `subprocess.check_output` returns what you really want: the command output (in this case, the list of PIDs)

Comment: You are right. I got confused between the behavior of `check_call` and `check_output`.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using windows,
you can get PID of process/app with it's image name with this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_pid_of_app(app_image_name):
    final_list = []
    command = Popen(['tasklist', '/FI', f'IMAGENAME eq {app_image_name}', '/fo', 'CSV'], stdout=PIPE, shell=False)
    msg = command.communicate()
    output = str(msg[0])
    if 'INFO' not in output:
        output_list = output.split(app_image_name)
        for i in range(1, len(output_list)):
            j = int(output_list[i].replace("\"", '')[1:].split(',')[0])
            if j not in final_list:
                final_list.append(j)

    return final_list
```

it will return you all PID of a app like firefox or chrome e.g.

```
>>> get_pid_of_app("firefox.exe")
[10908, 4324, 1272, 6936, 1412, 2824, 6388, 1884]
```

let me know if it helped

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Unix base use this code:

```
import os
def check_process(name):
    output = []
    cmd = "ps -aef | grep -i '%s' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $2 }' > /tmp/out"
    os.system(cmd % name)
    with open('/tmp/out', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            output.append(line.strip())
            line = f.readline()
            if line.strip():
                output.append(line.strip())

    return output
```

Then call it and pass it a process name to get all PIDs.

```
>>> check_process('firefox')
['499', '621', '623', '630', '11733']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.5, [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) is recommended over [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api):

```
>>> int(subprocess.run(["pidof", "-s", "your_process"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)
```

Also, since Python 3.7, you can use the `capture_output=true` parameter to capture stdout and stderr:

```
>>> int(subprocess.run(["pidof", "-s", "your process"], capture_output=True).stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, you can use [`pyproc2`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproc2) package.

###### Installation

```
pip install pyproc2
```

###### Usage

```py
import pyproc2
chrome_pid=pyproc2.find("chrome").pid #Returns PID of first process with name "chrome"
```