# Find PID of a daemon?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, pid

Hey guys I am using elasticsearch and I ran it as a daemon...unfortunately now I don't know how to terminate it. whenever i go to 9200 i always get this:

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Patsy Walker",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.4",
    "build_hash" : "0d3159b9fc8bc8e367c5c40c09c2a57c0032b32e",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-12-15T11:25:18Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

which i know means it is still up. how would i find the PID and then kill it?

Comment: `pidof nameofthedaemon`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/python-how-to-get-pid-by-process-name

Comment: @nsilent22how do u get the name of the daemon?

Comment: what os is elasticsearch running on?

Comment: @ccf its running on mac

Answer (score 2):

To find the PID, try this:

```
ps -ef | grep elasticsearch | xargs | awk '{print $2}'
```

To kill it:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

I have little experience with Mac. This link may help in finding a proper way to stop a daemon:
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Cannot-kill-ElasticSearch-process-Mac-OS-X-es-version-0-19-10-td4028808.html