# How to test whether a linux application is running using python?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

How can I tell whether a specific application is running on my linux system (using python?).

For example I run Minecraft via a runnable jar file. Where does the system store that that process is running? Or if I run a simple "Hello world" python script with a wait call at the end (keeping the thread alive indefinitely), how could I test whether that thread was still alive or not from another python script?

The sudo code for what I want is roughly:
isProcRunning(minecraft) or isProcRunning(home/usr/exampleScript)

I know that the Proc virtual file system exists, but I am unsure how to use it appropriately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at the output of `ps` from the commandline

Comment: *Aside*: [`sudo` code](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) and ["pseudo-code"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pseudocode) don't mean the same thing.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/python-how-to-get-pid-by-process-name).

Comment: @Robᵩ, using sudo instead of psuedo is a linux joke :p