# How to get Process ID with name in python

Tags: python, command-line, process, subprocess, pid

I am trying to build a simple python script that does one thing right now: it finds the process id of a process given it's PID. I have looked on here and found many different resources, but none that quite fit what I need. The most helpful is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/how-to-get-pid-by-process-name-in-python) and I have used their example to try to make progress.

Right now I have this:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])

print(get_pid("fud"))
```

I am using sudo top to view all my processes in a different terminal window. There is one process in particular named "fud" that I see on the screen and know that it is running. When I run the program for that process and any other process I get this:

```
  File "fort.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(get_pid("fud"))
  File "fort.py", line 4, in get_pid
    return check_output(["pidof",name])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am not really sure what is going on here, and would like detailed guidance on an effective way to correct this mistake and do what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to run `pidof fud` in your shell?

Comment: No I haven't. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: `check_output` simply runs a command in a shell and return its output. So, at first, check if this command correct. Run `pidof fud` in your shell (bash).

Answer (score 1):

I have since found the solution. It is very simple:

```py
print(commands.getoutput('pgrep FortniteClient-Mac-Shipping'))
```

Hope someone can use this one day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psutil` package:

**Install**

```
pip install psutil
```

**Usage:**
In order to get process id using process name refer the following snippet:

```py
import psutil

process_name = "fud"

def get_pid(process_name):
   for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       if proc.name() == process_name:
          return proc.pid
```