# Unable to get PID of a process by name in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a very simple piece of code

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(["pidof","ffmpeg"]))
```

that should print the PID(s) of processes named `ffmpeg` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/how-to-get-pid-by-process-name)). However, I always get the following error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pidof', 'ffmpeg']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

for python2 and python3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it because there will be no process currently active by name `"ffmpeg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man pidof`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      At least one program was found with the requested name.

       1      No program was found with the requested name.
```

You just don't have any process named `ffmpeg`.

Comment: But when I run the same command on bash, I do not get an error message. But an exit of 1 though

Comment: `check_output` is designed to raise `CalledProcessError` if process exited with non-zero code: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 1):

you can use try except to avoid the execution from blocking

use this

```
import subprocess

try:

    print(subprocess.check_output(["pidof","ffmpeg"]))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("no process named ffmpeg")
```

you are getting error because if `pidof ffmpeg` gives no output and using 
`print(subprocess.check_output(["pidof","ffmpeg"]))` we are expecting output from that command.

also you can use

`print(subprocess.getoutput("pidof ffmpeg"))`

which will give no error even if output from that command is `none`

if you check the library method `check_output` you can find this

```
def check_output(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Run command with arguments and return its output.

    If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.  The
    CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
    attribute and output in the output attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.... """
```